# Codeigniter 2.1 - counting the array before get

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this function:

```
   function gi_get_by($col,$id, $itd, $tbl, $limit = 10)
        {    
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('global_info');
        $this->db->join($tbl, 'id_' . $tbl . ' = id_global_info');
        $this->db->where('info_type_id', $itd);
        if($col == 'date_created' || $col == 'tag') {$this->db->like($col, $id);}        
        else {$this->db->where($col, $id);}
        if($tbl == 'ad') :
        $this->db->order_by('paid', 'desc');
        endif;
        $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'desc');  
        $this->db->limit($limit, $this->uri->segment(2));
        $q = $this->db->get();        
        return $q = $q->result_array();   
        }
```

What I need is to count number of results before limit and to use them later in controller. I have an idea to duplicate this function without **$limit** but then it will be duplicating the same function. Is there another way to do this or I have to go with duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to do but if you want an optional limit you can default it to false:

```
 function gi_get_by($col,$id, $itd, $tbl, $limit=false)
        {    
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('global_info');
        $this->db->join($tbl, 'id_' . $tbl . ' = id_global_info');
        $this->db->where('info_type_id', $itd);
        if($col == 'date_created' || $col == 'tag') {$this->db->like($col, $id);}        
        else {$this->db->where($col, $id);}
        if($tbl == 'ad') :
        $this->db->order_by('paid', 'desc');
        endif;
        $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'desc');
        if ($limit) {  
          $this->db->limit($limit, $this->uri->segment(2));
        }
        $q = $this->db->get();        
        return $q = $q->result_array();   
        }
```

This will conditionally add limit clause if it is passed in to the function.

Also it would be best to pass in wwhatever `$this->uri->segment(2)` into the function as a parameter instead of accessing it from within the function.

Comment: Didn't think of that at all. It is working. Thank you for the help and tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not select

```
sql_calc_found_rows
```

in your query?

http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2008/07/01/mysql-php-sql_calc_found_rows-an-easy-way-to-get-the-total-number-of-rows-regardless-of-limit/

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about something like this:

```
function gi_get_by($col,$id, $itd, $tbl, $limit = 10)
{
    $count = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table')->num_rows();

    //the rest stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Active Record Cache:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#caching

```
function gi_get_by($col,$id, $itd, $tbl, $limit = 10)
{    
    // Start the cache
    $this->db->start_cache();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('global_info');
    $this->db->join($tbl, 'id_' . $tbl . ' = id_global_info');
    $this->db->where('info_type_id', $itd);
    if($col == 'date_created' || $col == 'tag') {$this->db->like($col, $id);}        
    else {$this->db->where($col, $id);}
    if($tbl == 'ad') :
    $this->db->order_by('paid', 'desc');
    endif;
    $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'desc');

    // Stop the cache
    $this->db->stop_cache();

    // Get the total
    $total = $this->db->count_all_results();

    // Now set the limit
    $this->db->limit($limit, $this->uri->segment(2));

    $q = $this->db->get();

    // Important! Clear the cache
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    return $q = $q->result_array();   
}
```

Comment: How can I latter use $total in controller? At the moment this function is returning result_array.

Comment: You can put it in a class property, or separate this function into three functions.

Comment: My bad. I need it to count results before limit and to be able to use it latter. dm03514 way is working, and it is simple and fast. Nevertheless, thank you for your help :)